# Creating a structure with Jobs, Events, Listeners, Queues in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-8, laravel-jobs, laravel-events

I have a flow about that. I can solve the problem on paper. As a system admin, we have the following models: Clients, Departments, Users, Visitors, Calls, and Meetings.

- **Clients** are our customers.
- **Departments** are customers' departments.
- **Users** have many roles, but we inspect the "Agent" role to define the
  agent as a call center worker.
- **Visitors** are those who want to meet
  with an active agent by selecting a client and department.
- **Calls** are a log table. If visitors can find the agent and send data to the
  agent, I store data in the call table.
- **Meetings** If the agent accepts the call, I store it in the meeting table and notify the
  agent and visitor.

**Client.php (Model)**

```
public function users(){
   return $this->hasMany(User::class);
}
public function departments(){
   return $this->hasMany(Department::class);
}
```

**Department.php (Model)**

```
public function department_users(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'department_user');
}
public function client(){
    return $this->belongsToMany(Client::class, 'client_id');
}
```

**User.php (Model)**

```
public function departments(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class, 'department_user');
}
```

**Visitor.php (Model)**

```
public function department(){
  return $this->belongsTo(Department::class);
}
```

So as you can see, we define the relationships, and we want to do something like that:

Here is the flow...

[image: 1]

The question is, how can I do that in Laravel 8?

Comment: Hi! Please take a look to this websites, they might bel helpufl: 
* https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.7/tutorials/getting-started-models.html#getting-started-model-first
* https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent